# raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Tags: python, selenium

from selenium import webdriver
`from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys` import time

``PATH ="/home/j_a_r_v_i_s/Desktop/CODE/Email/chromedriver"

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)` driver.get("https://techwithtim.net")

`search = driver.find_element_by_name("s")` search.send_keys("hello")
``search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

``print(driver.title)

Answer (score 0):

This error

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

You have to provide the path for chome binary

`Chromedriver` is not installed in your System by default. Users individually have to download chromedriver from [ChromeDriver - WebDriver](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/) for Chrome page and you can place it anywhere within your system.

You must ensure that Chrome is installed at the optimum location as the server expects you to have Chrome installed in the default location for each system as per the snapshot below :

[image]

Then your code will be look like, for example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files\\Chrome\\chrome101.0.4951.67\\chrome.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://google.com/')
print("Chrome Browser Invoked")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: @Vijay, Please accept the answer if your issue is resolved.